# Android Environment.getExternalStorageState return mounted when SD not present

Tags: android, android-external-storage

First exposure to code up external SD file saving.   Not sure I understand why when I call Environment.getExternalStorageState() I get back "mounted" even through the SD card is removed?

Comment: That is because [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices.

Comment: So what am I missing in order to determine if I should save to internal memory or save downloaded file to external SD card?

Comment: In general, you can't "save downloaded file to external SD card", except on Android 4.4+, and even there only in limited situations.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking I was not thinking this all the way through.  I have an app right now that saves files to the External (which is really internal) SD.  I've had a request to allow them to be stored on the truly external SD and looking how to enable that option to the user.

Comment: Either use the stuff I outlined in [the blog post on removable storage that I linked to in my original comment and am linking to again right now](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) or use [the Storage Access Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CommonsWare answered this best with:

Either use the stuff I outlined in the blog post on removable storage that I linked to in my original comment and am linking to again right now or use the Storage Access Framework.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html